# Construct a function $f: R\to R$ that has discontinuities at every point x in A and is continuous on A complement.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not sure where to start or how to even attempt this problem. I need to find a function for $A= \{x \in \mathbb R |0\leq x \leq 1 \}\cup {2}$.

Help please!

Comment: Uh-A={2} and A= [0,1] ?Does that make sense? You must have made a mistake.

Comment: I edited your question-is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following mapping where A =[0,1}$\cup${2} and f:**R**$\rightarrow$**R** defined by:If $0\leq x \leq 1$ or x=2, then f(x) =1 iff x is rational and 0 if x is not rational. If $x\notin [0,1]$, then f(x) = x.It's easy to check f is discontinuous at every x in A= [0,1] and continuous everywhere else on the real line. Notice this function covers the case where x = 2 since 2 is rational i.e. 2 = $\frac{2}{1}$.

I'm not sure if this is the domain you wanted, your question isn't that clear. But this should give you the kind of function you're seeking and it's easily modified.

Answer (score 1):

According to the title of your question..Although the function is NOT defined on your set $A$.

Consider Thomae's function...which is discontinuous at all rational points , i.e. in the set $\mathbb Q$..but is continuous in $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$.

Consider , $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if } x=0\\0 & \text{ for }  x\text{ is irrational. }\\\frac{1}{q} & \text{ if } x=\frac{p}{q}\text{ where }p,q\text{ are relatively prime with }q\not =0\end{cases}$$

Comment: I think your function is continuous at 0...

Comment: No..think about nbd. of $0$.................@neela

Comment: how to prove discontinuous at zero?

Comment: if a seq of rational converges to zero its image seq also converges to zero..

Comment: @neela) See [the proof here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077028/explanation-of-proof-for-discontinuity-of-thomaes-function)

Comment: If $A\subset R$ then there exists $f:R\to R$ which  is continuous at each $x\in R\backslash A$ and discontinuous at each $x\in A$ if and only if  $A$ is an  $F_{\sigma}$ set in $R$.

Comment: On this proof value at zero?